# How to draw independent line with pencil in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I drew 2 circles with circle tool, one inside another. Then I switched to pencil tool and drew a line for future callout. But the line damaged previous circleto for continuous path.

[image]

How to turn this feature off? I need just to draw line where I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other situations, it is a helpful feature to automatically continue working an already  selected path that is at very close proximity to the point where you start to draw... You can switch it off in the Pencil tool options: Double-click on the Pencil button in the tool panel, and then un-check the option to **Edit selected Paths**.

[image: Adobe Illustrator: Screenshot of Pencil Tool Options]

Answer (score 0):

Lock the circle, or put it on a new layer and lock the layer.

Comment: I can't lock all my drawings all the time. I need they behave good by default. How to tell tools not to try being more smart than me?